# Button not displaying properly on edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

Just wondering why this doesn't have the expected behaviour on edge? it works just fine on Chrome and Firefox. Not really sure what's going on.  I've tried to research this but I really don't know where to start. Doesn't edge use the -webkit- prefix? 
The correct behaviour is what you see on Chrome and Firefox.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("cb4");
checkbox.indeterminate = true;
```

```css
body {
font-family:arial;
}

.flipswitch {
position: relative;
background: white;
width: 120px;
height: 40px;
-webkit-appearance: initial;
-moz-appearance: initial;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
outline:none;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
cursor:pointer;
border:1px solid #ddd;
}

.flipswitch:indeterminate:after {
position:absolute;
top:5%;
display:block; 
line-height:32px;
width:45%;
height:90%;
box-sizing:border-box;
text-align:center;
color:black;
border:#888 1px solid;
border-radius:3px;
}

.flipswitch:not(:indeterminate):after {
-webkit- position:absolute;
top:5%;
display:block; 
line-height:32px;
width:45%;
height:90%;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
text-align:center;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
color:black;
border:#888 1px solid;
border-radius:3px;
}

.flipswitch:indeterminate:after {
left:30%;
content:"???";
background:grey;
}

.flipswitch:not(:indeterminate):after {
left:2%;
content: "OFF";
background:#f00;
}

.flipswitch:not(:indeterminate):checked:after {
left:53%;
content: "ON";  
background:#0f0;
}
```

```html
<!--Marketing Emails -->
<div class="form-row">
  <h4>Do you wish to receive Zoek Marketing Emails</h4>
  <p>Emails reminding you to keep your account updated, and to continue your job search with Zoek</p>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" class="flipswitch" name="marketing"/>&nbsp;
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that edge uses the -webkit- prefix. If I remember correctly to support edge you need something like this:

```
    /* Microsoft Edge Browser 12+ (All) - @supports method */

@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .selector { property:value; } 
}
```

Which is the -ms- prefix for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

If you need more info on specific versions of edge browsers and how to support them you can take a look here: https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/css-hacks-for-windows-10-and-spartan-browser-preview/

EDIT: as you can see here the -webkit-appearance is already working for edge:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

There is going to be a problem in your css somewhere else. At the moment I don't have time to completely adjust your code to what you need (work and stuff...), but I do have a working example that works on edge: https://codepen.io/mrdeadsven/pen/KewdgE
You can probably adjsut yout code to something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my CSS to look like this https://codepen.io/boolie205/pen/yELoGP   but it still doesn't work, is this the kind of thing the article means?

Comment: @LewisClarke check my edits i made in my answer, hope it helps.